# is Euler's method stable for this problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

Consider the IVP
\begin{align*}
y''=-y
\end{align*}
for $t \geq 0$, and $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=2$.

I have rewritten this differential equation as a system of first-order ODE's such that
\begin{align*}
u'=v\\
v'=-u\\
\end{align*}
with $u(0)=1, v(0)=2$.

The solution is $y=2\sin(t)+\cos(t)$, $y'=2\cos(t)-\sin(t)$.

I am asked to perform one step of Euler's method with $h=0.5$, and determine if Euler's method is stable for this problem.

For the first part, I find that one step of Euler's method yields
\begin{align*}
y_1=y_0+hf(t_0, y_0)=1+(0.5)(2\cos(0)-\sin(0))=2.
\end{align*}
But how do I determine if Euler's method is stable? I know that for the equation $y'=\lambda y$, Euler's method is stable for $|1+h\lambda| \leq 1$, but since this problem is in a different form I'm not sure what I need to do here.

Thanks !

Comment: can be typo for $ v=y^{'} ?$

Comment: I let $u=y, v=y'$, so that $u'=y'=v$, and $v'=y''=-y=-u$.

Comment: What does stability mean for a system with eigenvalues $\pm i$? That the numerical method gives a bounded result? How can you observe that in just one step? // You need to apply the method to the first order system $u'=v$, $v'=-u$ that you constructed. Please correct the question to the correct first order system without $y$.

Comment: I was asked in a previous question if the system is stable. Since the eigenvalues are $\pm i$, i.e., Re($\lambda_1$)=0 and Re($\lambda_2$)=0, the system is stable. But now the question is whether or not the system is stable particularly for Euler's method, and I'm not sure how to determine that.

Comment: How can the method be applied to the system?

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Euler iteration procedure we have

$$
\cases{
u_k = u_{k-1}+h v_{k-1}\\
v_k = v_{k-1}-h u_{k-1}
}
$$

or

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_k\\
v_k
\end{array}\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & h \\
 -h & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{k-1}\\
v_{k-1}
\end{array}\right)
$$

or

$$
U_k = M^k U_0
$$

this sequence converges as long as the eigenvalues of $M$ have absolute value less than $1$. Here the $M$ eigenvalues are $1\pm i h$ with absolute value $\sqrt{1+h^2} > 1$ so the Euler procedure diverges.

Answer (score 0):

You apply the Euler step to the first-order system. 
$$u_1=u_0+hu_0'=u_0+hv_0,\\ v_1=v_0+hv_0'=v_0-hu_0.$$ As the Euler step is tangential to the convex solution curve, it will always move outwards, away from the center of the concentric exact solution curves.

Comment: Do you mind explaining a bit more about "the Euler step is tangential to the convex solution curve"?

Comment: The solutions in phase space are concentric circles, the Euler step is a line segment in tangential direction from the current circle. Draw yourself a picture to see that you get an outward spiral.